# Pull out data from a file and store it in strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have a file which contains records of students in the following format.

```
Umar|Ejaz|12345|umar@umar.com
Majid|Hussain|12345|majid@majid.com
Ali|Akbar|12345|ali@geeks-inn.com
Mahtab|Maqsood|12345|mahtab@myself.com
Juanid|Asghar|12345|junaid@junaid.com
```

The data has been stored according to the following format:

```
firstName|lastName|contactNumber|email
```

The total number of lines(records) can not exceed the limit 100. In my program, I've defined the following string variables.

```
#define MAX_SIZE 100
// other code
string firstName[MAX_SIZE];
string lastName[MAX_SIZE];
string contactNumber[MAX_SIZE];
string email[MAX_SIZE];
```

Now, I want to pull data from the file, and using the delimiter '|', I want to put data in the corresponding strings. I'm using the following strategy to put back data into string variables.

```
ifstream readFromFile;  
readFromFile.open("output.txt");
// other code
int x = 0;
string temp;

while(getline(readFromFile, temp)) {
    int charPosition = 0;
    while(temp[charPosition] != '|') {
        firstName[x] += temp[charPosition];
        charPosition++;
    }
    while(temp[charPosition] != '|') {
        lastName[x] += temp[charPosition];
        charPosition++;
    }
    while(temp[charPosition] != '|') {
        contactNumber[x] += temp[charPosition];
        charPosition++;
    }
    while(temp[charPosition] != endl) {
        email[x] += temp[charPosition];
        charPosition++;
    }
    x++;
}
```

Is it necessary to attach null character '\0' at the end of each string? And if I do not attach, will it create problems when I will be actually implementing those string variables in my program. I'm a new to C++, and I've come up with this solution. If anybody has better technique, he is surely welcome.

Edit: Also I can't compare a char(acter) with endl, how can I?

Edit: The code that I've written isn't working. It gives me following error.

```
     Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Note: I can only use .txt file. A .csv file can't be used.

Comment: yes. a string which isn't null-terminate will cause ALL kinds of trouble when you're writing C-style code. e.g. `strlen()` will return some insane value because it'll keep scanning the string until it DOES find a null value, which could be "never".

Comment: I'll be writing all the code in C++, never in C. So will it cause problem(s) in C++?

Comment: why you do: firstName[x] += temp[charPosition]; ?  and not only = (equal) and the x var always have the same value on each while, so all your chars from the file are written on the 0 position of each string, overwritting the last one.

Comment: That is a tricky part. firstName[0] ( say x is 0 ) is a string, not a char. So each time I do firstName[0] += temp[charPosition], a new character gets added or appended to the string firstName[0].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't terminate a a C-style string with a null character there is no way to determine where the string ends. Thus, you'll need to terminate the strings.

I would personally read the data into `std::string` objects:

```
std::string first, last, etc;
while (std::getline(readFromFile, first, '|')
    && std::getline(readFromFile, last, '|')
    && std::getline(readFromFile, etc)) {
    // do something with the input
}
```

`std::endl` is a manipulator implemented as a function template. You can't compare a `char` with that. There is also hardly ever a reason to use `std::endl` because it flushes the stream after adding a newline which makes writing really slow. You probably meant to compare to a newline character, i.e., to `'\n'`. However, since you read the string with `std::getline()` the line break character will already be removed! You need to make sure you don't access more than `temp.size()` characters otherwise.

Your record also contains arrays of strings rather than arrays of characters and you assign individual `char`s to them. You either wanted to yse `char something[SIZE]` or you'd store strings!

Answer (score 4):

There are many techniques to do this.  I suggest searching StackOveflow for "[C++] read file" to see some more methods.

**Find and Substring**
You could use the `std::string::find` method to find the delimiter and then use `std::string::substr` to return a substring between the position and the delimiter.

```
std::string::size_type position = 0;
positition = temp.find('|');
if (position != std::string::npos)
{
    firstName[x] = temp.substr(0, position);
}
```

Comment: That is magic. Very intuitive. I'd love to use it. But can you please tell me what is wrong with my code, because it is not working, it is giving me error of Segmentation fault (core dumped) and I don't know why isn't it working?

Comment: When you single-stepped with the debugger, which line is failing?

Comment: I'm new to C++ and this world. So I'm not using a C++ debugger. I'm writing my simple programs and running them through g++ using commmand line tools on Ubuntu.

Comment: Try a program called gdb.  Search the web for manual.  It's on Ubuntu.